# how can get a higher amplitude in this differentiator invertor amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, simulation, components

Im a bit confused since Im missing how to control the output amplitude in this circuit
[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1],]

it yields the next output

[image]

AFAIK, the bias compensation resistor must be the same that the feedback one, and the output is controled using the C1 for the pulse width and the R1 for the amplitude of it.
But even if using other values of R1,R2 (the same or different) and C1 the opamp seems to be always saturated like this
[image]
I was expecting to get one squared signal of 2Vpp. So in the end if I use values for the components different to the ones showed it get saturated and if not the ouput is too short.

**UPDATE**
Thanks to devnull, the configuration followed was the next, (it was  easy ). It takes only to aument the value of C1 to 500p. But it also worked if the R1 is raised. Thanks a lot!!!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Tip: untangle your schematic so that it's clear what the *schema* is. This will help you and  us.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I didnt take in account the position of the instrument and sources

Comment: Let us know when you reach the final values and the plot matches the circuit.

Comment: of course, I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the circuit below, focus on **C1** and **R1** to understand the differentiator behavior:

[image]

Assuming \$V_z\$ always zero, \$\frac{dV}{dt}\$ at the capacitor is \$\frac{1V}{10ms}\$, so:

\$I_c = C \frac{dv}{dt} = 100 nF * \frac{1V}{10ms} = 10 \mu A\$

Considering this current goes only through **R1**:

\$V_{out} = -10\mu A * 100k\Omega = -1V\$

[image]

**R2** and **C2**, with such small values, affect the transient behavior but not the output amplitude. **R3** compensates the error caused by the offset current, which is probably not relevant for the values involved.

> how can get a higher amplitude in this differentiator/inverter amplifier?

Increase **C1** and/or **R1**.